# Can I use my VirtualBox 3.* VMs with VirtualBox 4.0? If so, how come the repository doesn't have it?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, updates

I had the following repository for virtualbox in my /etc/apt/sources.list: `deb ttp://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian maverick non-free`

Then I found out there was a new version when I opened it today (the program prompted me with a window to manually download it from Oracle's site). Then I tried `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade and got nothing`.

[Here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/virtualbox-4-0-2-released-and-ubuntu-10-1010-049-10-installation-instructions-included.html) you have a way to add virtualbox-4.0 to your apt-get, but the problem is that it isn't updating, meaning I would have the two installed. I'm also worried if I'll have to do something like that each time it updates since that would defeat the point of apt-get.

I've been using virtualbox with the apt-get update for more than a year now and this is the first time it has happened, so I was wondering if there would be a way to just update my current installation.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual Box 4.0 is a major update. The previous version still needs to be supported. To acchieve this the Virtual Box repository will be available for both, the 3.x and the 4.x version.

If you want to run the latest version you need to add the 4.x repository to your sources. This is perfectly explained on the [Virtual Box download page](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

Before installing Virtual Box 4.0. you need to remove the previous version. Your private virtual machines will not be affected. However you will need to reinstall the newer Guest Additions, and if you need RDP or USB support you will also need to install the Oracle Vitual Box Extension Pack.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox 4 quite new and has a different package name as to not force everybody to upgrade at once (they still support 3.x IIRC).

To install it, add the repository, as you have and then just:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.0
```

This package is set to conflict with 3.x so that will be removed as part of the process. As far as I know, you can't run both at the same time as they would have conflicting kernel modules.

Comment: The repo link also changed, non-free => contrib. Now: `deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian maverick contrib`. As that often happens I always give the link to virtualbox.org download page.